# How to read env files by runnnig Go application?

Tags: go

I have an application which is developed in Go. I have a `config.env` file and get some critical variables from it by using the `godotenv` library. Here is the code:

```
func InitializeEnvVars() error {
    err := godotenv.Load("./config.env")
    return err
}
```

When I build my project with `go build .` on MacOS and I want to run the application, the app gives an error about reading the `.env` file:

`2021/03/07 17:42:21 [ERROR]: Error loading .env file`

But when I run my app with `go run main.go` command, everything works well.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: when running the program built with `go build .`, are you running the executable in the same directory as `config.env`?

Comment: @jakub sure. The executable file and config.env are in the same folder.

Comment: The location of the executable is irrelevant. Only the working directory matters.

Comment: So, what is your suggestion?

Answer (score 3):

As per the comments `godotenv.Load("./config.env")` will attempt to load the `.env` file from the working directory. The method used to set the working directory depends upon how you are starting the application (i.e. command line/gui).

If you would prefer that the `.env` be loaded from the folder holding the executable then try the following (note that there are some [caveats](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#Executable)).

```
ex, err := os.Executable()
if err != nil {
    panic(fmt.Sprintf("Failed to get executable path: %s", err))
}
envPath := filepath.Join(filepath.Dir(ex), ".env")
err = godotenv.Load(envPath)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find the solution below step by step:

- Create a folder like `cmd`
- Move executable file to the folder
- Create `env` file with written named in the code into this folder
- Open terminal (zsh - MacOS) and run this command: `open <executableFileName>`

**Output file should be in separated folder.**